# Create a custom Stanford Tokenizer

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp

I am involved in building an Natural Language Application which should recognize entities which could involve machine types i.e. for example x86 would be a type. In addition it would be great if the NER could recognize a file location, i.e. something like /foobar/data/ or a file at a location i.e. /foobar/data/example.zip

Now obviously one could train the Stanford Parser to arrive at these. But before creating a training sample, I have to create the labeled token file. The instructions are pretty clear [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml). However I had an issue while tokenization. One can't expect the Stanford Parser to tokenize a file like /foobar/data/example.zip as a single token. I just want to tag such a file location as a single token and then obviously label it as a FILE-LOCATION. ( I would be asking a lot if you knew the right ENTITY TAG I should use, I am going through the ACE entity types, but if you can point me to the standard tags that are used for machine type entities and events, it would be really helpful.)

So my question is this :

I want to customize the stanford tokenizer or rather extend it to understand file locations or custom tokens. How can this be done? ( Is this even required for before the NER step? )

I was looking at the options the Stanford Tokenizer has [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) and I wasn't sure of how to train a new tokenizer.